# Отправка писем через SmtpLib Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Допустим, есть код:

```
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('example@gmail.com','example123')                          
mail.sendmail('example@gmail.com','example_1@gmail.com','Message Text')
mail.close()
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как мне добавить заголовок к этому письму *без использования* MIMETEXT?

Comment: Чем вам mimetext не угодил-то?

Comment: @andreymal Написал уже много кода,а исправлять лень

Comment: Ну так вам в любом случае его исправлять, чтобы заголовок добавить, не?)

Comment: @andreymal Ну,я нашел варианты добавления с MIMEText,там нужно не одну строку менять,а вообще все.

Comment: @andreymal Вот и интересуюсь, может есть какой-нибудь дедовский способ

Answer (score 1):

Пробуй это:

```
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('example@gmail.com','example123') 
FROM = 'example@gmail.com'
TO = 'example_1@gmail.com'
BODY = "\r\n".join((
"From: %s" % FROM,
"To: %s" % TO,
"Subject: %s" % SUBJECT ,
"",
text
))
mail.sendmail(FROM,[TO],BODY)
mail.close()
```

Comment: Это,конечно,работает, но мне бы без вот этого:FROM = 'example@gmail.com'
TO = 'example_1@gmail.com'
BODY = "\r\n".join((
"From: %s" % FROM,
"To: %s" % TO,
"Subject: %s" % SUBJECT ,
"",
text

Comment: Хорошо. Попробуй убрать FROM и TО, а в sendmail-e написать сами ящики

Comment: Я не знаю как это объяснить...Мне нужно, чтобы Subject работал 1 строкой как 'Subject = '123'' или 'mail.sendmail('отправитель','получатель','текст письма','заголовок'),без вот этой 'перестановки'.Просто код очень большой и менять придется очень долго.

Comment: @QqqqSsss, оберните код в функцию и передавайте в нее параметры. Код в 9 строк еще небольшой

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй тогда этот код. Тут я MIME текста не вижу)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import smtplib
    def mail(sender, subject, message, to):
        smtp_server = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
        smtp_port = 25
        smtp_pasword = 'pew_pew99'
        mail_lib = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
        mail_lib.login(sender, smtp_pasword)
        # В случае если функции передан не список с получателями
        # а обычную строку
        if isinstance(to, str):
            to = ','.join(to)
        msg = 'From: %s\r\nTo: %s\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\r\nSubject: %s\r\n\r\n' % (sender, to, subject)
        msg += message
        mail_lib.sendmail(sender, to, msg)
    # отправляем письмо
    message = """
    Привет из Python!
    """
    mail('JessePinkman@yandex.ru', 'Yeah Bitch! Magnets!', message, 'Walter_White@yahoo.com')
```

Comment: Вот! Получилось cont = 'Subject: 123',только я теперь не знаю как само сообщение отправить.